# IIS 7 suddenly stops serving static assets

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've a production web server running IIS 7 that since mid-December has randomly stopped serving static assets (css, jpg, ico, js, ico, etc) on 6 occasions.

Each time there are no error log entries on the server, the CMS C# ASP.NET application is serving the HTML without fault.  Reviewing IIS logs does not reveal any unusual pattern (including DDOS), but does not record any requests to the assets.  Using Fiddler to monitor requests shows the requests as not being answered (again no errors until connection timeout).

Restarting the web publishing service fixes the fault.

With no error messages and the only symptom being the files just not being served I'm at a loss, any ideas welcome.